# CreateObject causing App Pool to hang

Tags: vb.net, iis

I am running this VB.NET code to convert WAV files to mp3s.  It typically runs about 20 times an hour. Randomly, about once a day, the app pool hangs on `objMP3 = CreateObject("AudioConverter.AudioConverterx")`.  Restarting the app pool fixes it.

```
'convert the file
objMP3 = CreateObject("AudioConverter.AudioConverterx")
objMP3.Logfile = myLogFileName
objMP3.Convert(myWAVfile, myMP3file, "-cMP3")
objMP3 = Nothing
```

Every time this happens, the Event Log has this error:

> Faulting application w3wp.exe, version 6.0.3790.3959, stamp 45d6968e,
>   faulting module audioconverter.dll, version 0.0.0.0, stamp 2a425e19,
>   debug? 0, fault address 0x0000402e.

And the system log has this:

> A process serving application pool 'tts.servername.com' exceeded time
>   limits during shut down. The process id was '1340'.

The only thing that I can think of is that the application isn't being closed properly.  I've read that `objMP3 = Nothing` doesn't actually close it (or it doesn't work the same as in classic vb).

I have also set up Debug Diagnostics on the server.  When the hang occurs, a large file (> 8GB) is created with only this line multiple times a second.

> [11/8/2011 9:28:36 PM] First chance exception - 0xc0000005 caused by
>   thread with  System ID: 2548

Any Ideas?

Comment: That COM server simply crashes with an access violation.  Pretty standard failure mode for native code.  You'll need to debug it or ditch it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to correctly release a COM object from .NET, and ensure it's finalizers are run, you should call [Marshall.ReleaseComObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx).

This is the code I use:

```
    'convert the file
    objMP3 = CreateObject("AudioConverter.AudioConverterx")
    ' Do stuff
    ReleaseComObject(objMP3)

    private void ReleaseComObject(object o)
    {
        try
        {
            if (o != null)
            {
                // As per the documentation, call ReleaseComObject in a loop
                // until all references are released.
                while (System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o) > 0)
                {
                }
            }

            o = null;
        }
        catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)
        {
            // Do nothing. We don't want exceptions to leak out of this method.
        }
    }
```